# UITextfield delegate method not getting called when text set programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

My `UIViewController` confirms to `UITextFieldDelegate` and implements delegate method:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
```

It also sets `delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`
All works fine when user enters text from keyboard. However, the above delegate method is not called when I set text programatically.
i.e `textField.text = "some text"`

I have also tried calling `textField.sendActions(for: .editingDidEnd)`. Please note that I need to trigger this delegate method while writing unit tests for my controller.

Comment: [*This method is called after the text field resigns its first responder status.*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619591-textfielddidendediting)Setting the `text` property in code does not change the status of the first responder.

Comment: All this does is describe the (correct) behavior. What's the question?

Comment: To be specific, question is that why textField.sendActions(for: .editingDidEnd) method is not causing to trigger the delegate method "func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)"

Answer (score 1):

Delegate methods respond to user input only. you need to manually call the delegate methods after setting the text.

Answer (score 0):

[From Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619591-textfielddidendediting) for `textFieldDidEndEditing`:

"This method is called after the text field resigns its first responder status."

You are changing the value of textField, not resigning it.

You could add an observer for `textDidChangeNotification`, which will notify you when text value is changed. [Refer to point 4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate)

Comment: I want the delegate method to be triggered "func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)", when text is set programatically. How can i forcibly trigger that?